# Movie with a private school, teacher, placard, and cheating students

Tags: identify-this-movie

What is the name of this movie? It's about a teacher who tries to teach values to their students. It is in a private prep school. The teacher has a placard over the door or high on the wall that he makes all students memorize. One of the students cheats on a test but the teacher can't prove it. Many years later, the student is rich & successful and challenges the teacher to another test, but he still cheats using a hidden microphone. The teacher asks him what was the quote on the placard and he can't remember because it's not in a book that his accomplice can access.

The movie has the feel of Dead Poet's Society, but it's not Dead Poet's Society. I tried to search for it but was unsuccessful:

[[1]](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=private-school&sort=user_rating,desc&mode=advanced&page=1&title_type=movie&ref_=kw_ref_typ), 
[[2]](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=cheating&sort=user_rating,desc&mode=advanced&page=1&title_type=movie&ref_=kw_ref_typ) &
[[3]](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=student%2Cteacher&sort=user_rating,desc&mode=advanced&page=1&title_type=movie&ref_=kw_ref_typ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [The Emperor's Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_Club) from 2002 with Kevin Kline about prep school teacher William Hundert facing student Sedgewick Bell, a Senator's son who cheats in a Classics competition. Many years later, Bell becomes a wealthy CEO and sets up a rematch, where:

> In a sense of deja vu, when Hundert notices Bell stumble on a question then recover, he notices that Sedgewick is wearing a tiny earpiece with which he is in contact with a graduate student feeding answers to him. Hundert once again asks an obscure question he first asked his class back in 1973, "Who was Shutruk-Nakhunte?", mentioned on a plaque [above his door] that all the other students knew about, but Bell, having been a late arrival (or never bothering to look at it), fails to answer.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: FWIW, I remembered Sedgewick Bell as a cross between (generals) John Sedgewick, and John Bell Hood, both of Civil War fame.